# Looking for a criterion for a subset of a complex variety to be of measure zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a surjective morphism of smooth complex varieties. Let $S$ be a subset of $X(\mathbb{C})$. I'm wondering if there are results that roughly say that if the intersection of $S$ with every fiber of $f$ is "small", then $S$ is "small". More specifically, suppose the following hold:

(i) For every $y\in Y(\mathbb{C})$, the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected and at least 1-dimensional. If necessary, also assume that every $f^{-1}(y)$ is smooth.

(ii) For every $y\in Y(\mathbb{C})$, the intersection
$$f^{-1}(y)\cap S$$
is a countable union of proper Zariski closed subsets of $f^{-1}(y)$.

Does it follow that $S$ is a set of measure zero (in $X(\mathbb{C})$, considered as a complex manifold)?

Any relevant results or references will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the setting of your question. However, perhaps you could say whether the [co-area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) is applicable?

Comment: Yes, this might be useful for my particular setting. Thanks.